# Firefox document.execCommand('insertText', ...)

Tags: html, firefox, textarea, execcommand

I know **FireFox** can deal with `execCommand` pretty well but this time I think I encountered a bug.

But maybe I'm just overlooking something.

I do have a `textarea` where I am executing `insertText` which just works fine as long as I am leaving the `textarea` or writing into it. When I want to execute a second time, it is written in text but not in value. Is it because of `insertText`?

Here is my example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea designMode="on" id="textarea"></textarea>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('textarea').focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Text'); return false;">Insert text</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('textarea').value = ''; return false;">Reset</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a solution for that? Unfortunately it isn't possible to use a `div contenteditable`.

Tested in **FireFox 41.0.2** with no **Add-Ons** enabled.

Comment: After a very long search this is what worked for me:
[How to Insert Text Into Textarea at Cursor Fast](https://www.everythingfrontend.com/posts/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position.html)

Answer (score 3):

The command `document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Text')` doesn't work in Firefox for `textarea`.

See bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696

Comment: thanks for your answer - see my answer on Lucky Chingi answer from 3rd Nov 15 (!)

Answer (score 0):

textarea should have **deginMode** On, not **Contenteditable**

Comment: thanks for your reply! But when I change **contenteditable** with **designMode** it doesn't let me execute **execCommand** - see updated question

Comment: seems to be to working fine on my server. Can you share what the error is or a screenshot?

Comment: you are also using **FireFox 41.0.2** with my named example? With `designMode="on"` I even can't `insertText`. With `contenteditable="true"` it works until I change value in the `textarea`

Comment: yes, 41.0.2 and you are correct DesignMode does not work on FF. Try this link while I find out more http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW/

Comment: thanks again for your reply! I tested this example. I think I saw this one somewhere at dev. mozilla. And it does work **but** it is a `div contenteditable` and like I said: with `contenteditable="true"` it does work with my textarea, until I change value.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#Rich_text_editing

Comment: you can try it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjZbQa when you click "Insert text" it will insert. Press the spacebar or any key you like and again on "Insert text". You will see it won't work when you changed the value of the textarea.

Comment: Inserted a bug ticket @mozilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696

Comment: @mikeazo unfortunately the bug was inserted to the wrong product ... I changed it to FF now. The bug itself is still neither assigned nor confirmed.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696

Comment: @mikeazo try [insert-text-textarea](https://github.com/bfred-it/insert-text-textarea) or [insert-text-at-cursor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/insert-text-at-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-browser zero-dependency library to insertText,
pls check it out :D https://github.com/fritx/insert-text-2

```js
import insert from 'insert-text-2'

editor.focus()
insert('Hello world!')
```

Related links:
- https://github.com/fritx/vue-at/issues/22#issuecomment-331762939
- [Firefox document.execCommand('insertText', ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480562/firefox-document-execcommandinserttext)